# Table width overflowing with the given data

Tags: tables, overflow

I like to have a table like this [image: Table]

However the table is growing towards right side and is exceeding the width. I have tried as--

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{type1cm}
%\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{newtxtext}       %
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}       % selects Times Roman as basic font
%\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
%Important
\addbibresource{references.bib}
% Math packages
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%Table packages
%Packages for Rotatebox
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
%\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
%\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
%\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
%\renewcommand\theadgape{}
%\setcellgapes{3pt}  % <--- new
\usepackage{siunitx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]

\caption{Sensor Data in Smart Healthcare}
\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{
           |c|
          >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|
          >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|
          >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|
          >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|
          }
\hline

 
    \textbf{Sl.No} & \textbf{Name of the Sensor} & \textbf{Measuring/Capturing Factor} & \textbf{Application in Smart Healthcare} & \textbf{Help in Disease Detection} \\
    \midrule
    1 & Accelerometer & Linear Acceleration & Use to capture the linear movement of a patient while performing any activities & Cardiac, Arthritis, Obesity, PCOD \\
    2 & Gyroscope & Angular Velocity & Use to capture the angular movement of a patient while performing any activities; such as rotation of the smart phone to change position & Cardiac, Arthritis, Obesity, PCOD \\
    3 & Image Sensor & Image \& Video & Use to capture the activities of a patient, while we need image data & Eye Health, Skin Health \\
    4 & Temperature & Body Temperature & Use to capture body temperature & Covid-19, Flu, Dengue, Pneumonia \\
    5 & Blood Pressure & Blood Pressure (Systolic and Diastolic) & Use to measure blood pressure of a patient & Cardiac, Obesity, PCOD \\
    6 & Oxygen Level & Oxygen level & Use to measure oxygen level in blood of a patient & Cardiac, Obesity, PCOD \\
    7 & Heart Rate & Heart Rate & Use to measure heart rates of a patient & Cardiac, Obesity, PCOD \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

Comment: column type `c`  centers the cell content in on line. You want something like `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}`. And clean up your preamble, you are loading various packages more then once, you are loading unneeded packages and the order is messy.

Comment: Changed to that but now getting the error-- **Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> ...egin \relax \d@llarend \endtemplate 
                                                  
l.102 ...textbf{Application in Smart Healthcare} &
                                                   \textbf{Help in Disease D...**

Comment: @Bukaida The line with `\textbf{Application in Smart Healthcare} & \textbf{Help in Disease D..` and other lines denoting table rows contain **four** `&` separating contents of **five** table cells while according to the tabular-environment's argument for specifying columns the table has only **four** columns.

Comment: @Bukaida Besides this, when specifying widths of columns so that the width of the entire table does not exceed `\textwidth`, you need to take into consideration that the rules of the table have the width `\arrayrulewidth` and that between a rule and the text of the column horizontal space of width `\tabcolsep` is inserted.

Comment: Yep, modified the code, now it is somewhat working.

Comment: Your table works fine. The only problem I see is use vertical lines and rules defined in `booktabs` package. I tested by standard `article` document class since I haven't `svmult`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't `svmult` documentclass, so I use `article. Hopefully in page design not differ to much and that table positioning in text complain the same rules.

I would rewrite your table a little bit: remove all vertical lines, from horizontal use only the first, second and the last one:

[image]

MWE:

```
%\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{newtxtext}          %
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}    % selects Times Roman as basic font

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp] 
\caption{Sensor Data in Smart Healthcare}
\footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} c X[l] X[1.32, l] X[2.2, l] X[1.5, l] @{}},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             row{1} = {c, m, font=\bfseries} 
            }
    \toprule
Sl.No   &   Name of the Sensor
            &   Measuring/Capturing Factor
                &   {Application in\\ Smart Healthcare}
                    &   {Help in\\ Disease Detection}
                        \\
    \midrule
1   &   Accelerometer 
        &   Linear Acceleration 
            &   Use to capture the linear movement of a patient while performing any activities
                &   Cardiac, Arthritis, Obesity, PCOD 
                    \\
2   &   Gyroscope 
        &   Angular Velocity 
            &   Use to capture the angular movement of a patient while performing any activities; such as rotation of the smart phone to change position 
                &   Cardiac, Arthritis, Obesity, PCOD 
                    \\
3   &   Image Sensor 
        &   Image \& Video 
            &   Use to capture the activities of a patient, while we need image data 
                &   Eye Health, Skin Health 
                    \\
4   &   Temperature 
        &   Body Temperature 
            &   Use to capture body temperature 
                &   Covid-19, Flu, Dengue, Pneumonia
                    \\
5   &   Blood Pressure 
        &   Blood Pressure (Systolic and Diastolic) 
            &   Use to measure blood pressure of a patient 
                &   Cardiac, Obesity, PCOD
                    \\
6   &   Oxygen Level 
        &   Oxygen level 
            &   Use to measure oxygen level in blood of a patient 
                &   Cardiac, Obesity, PCOD
                    \\
7   &   Heart Rate 
        &   Heart Rate 
            &   Use to measure heart rates of a patient 
                &   Cardiac, Obesity, PCOD
                    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Please test proposed solution with your document class and inform me, how much ther obtained result differ from mine showed above.

Answer (score 0):

I probably might do s.th. like this:

```latex
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}

\usepackage{newtxtext}%
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}% selects Times Roman as basic font

\usepackage{array, tabularx, booktabs}
% booktabs is only because I am too lazy to define \heavyrulewidth.

\usepackage[center]{caption}

\newlength\scratchlength

\begin{document}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\noindent Some text\hfill some text\hfill some text

\noindent A thick rule showing textwidth:

\medskip

\hrule height 1cm
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{table}[htbp]%
\caption{Sensor Data in Smart Healthcare}%
%..................................
\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}%
\settowidth\scratchlength{Sl.No}%
\def\arraystretch{1.25}%
%..................................
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
   !{\vrule width \heavyrulewidth}%
   >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\scratchlength}%
   |%
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X%
   |%
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X%
   |%
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X%
   |%
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X%
   !{\vrule width \heavyrulewidth}%
}%
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \noalign{\hrule height \heavyrulewidth}% <- This yields a \hline which is slightly thicker.
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \raggedright\textbf{Sl.No}&%
  \textbf{Name of the Sensor}&%
  \textbf{Measuring/\hskip0pt Capturing Factor}&%
  \textbf{Application in Smart Healthcare}&%
  \textbf{Help in Disease Detection}\\%
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %\noalign{\hrule height \lightrulewidth}%
  \noalign{\hrule height \heavyrulewidth}% <- This yields a \hline which is slightly thicker.
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1&%
  Accelerometer&%
  Linear Acceleration&%
  Use to capture the linear movement of a patient while performing any activities&%
  Cardiac, Arthritis, Obesity, PCOD\\%
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \hline
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2&%
  Gyroscope&%
  Angular Velocity&%
  Use to capture the angular movement of a patient while performing any activities;
    such as rotation of the smart phone to change position&%
  Cardiac, Arthritis, Obesity, PCOD\\%
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \hline
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3&%
  Image Sensor&%
  Image \& Video&%
  Use to capture the activities of a patient, while we need image data&%
  Eye Health, Skin Health\\%
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \hline
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  4&%
  Temperature&%
  Body Temperature&%
  Use to capture body temperature&%
  Covid-19, Flu, Dengue, Pneumonia\\%
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \hline
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  5&%
  Blood Pressure&%
  Blood Pressure (Systolic and Diastolic)&%
  Use to measure blood pressure of a patient&%
  Cardiac, Obesity, PCOD\\%
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \hline
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  6&%
  Oxygen Level&%
  Oxygen level&%
  Use to measure oxygen level in blood of a patient&%
  Cardiac, Obesity, PCOD\\%
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \hline
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  7&%
  Heart Rate&%
  Heart Rate&%
  Use to measure heart rates of a patient&%
  Cardiac, Obesity, PCOD\\%
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \noalign{\hrule height \heavyrulewidth}% <- This yields a \hline which is slightly thicker.
  %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]